# Iterating through PHP Array adds integer index to each item

Tags: php, arrays

I have a result array being returned from a search function in one of the models. Everything works fine, however, I have recently added an iteration block to redact a row of data based on an ID. Like so:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($searchResponse);$i++){
    if($searchResponse[$i]['id']==$user_id){
        unset($searchResponse[$i]);
    }
}
```

The code works fine and removes the appropriate data correctly. However it changes the array structure from this:

```
 "data":[
{
"id":"1",
"name_first":"Cameron",
"name_last":"Leafe",
"industry":"IT",
"workplace":"Leafe Interactive",
"imageURL":"https:\/\/scontent-b-kul.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xfa1\/t31.0-8\/p720x720\/819309_4979120151286_1476247244_o.jpg"
},
{
"id":"8",
"name_first":"Caroline",
"name_last":"McCullough",
"industry":"IT",
"workplace":"Occupation",
"imageURL":"http:\/\/www.mothersdelight.com\/avatar\/avatar.jpg"
},
{
"id":"11",
"name_first":"Akiko",
"name_last":"McDougall",
"industry":"IT",
"workplace":"Occupation",
"imageURL":"http:\/\/www.mothersdelight.com\/avatar\/avatar.jpg"
}
]
```

to this:

```
"data":{
"1":{
"id":"3",
"name_first":"Jane",
"name_last":"Doe",
"industry":"Retail - Fashion",
"workplace":"Big-W",
"imageURL":"http:\/\/www.johndoe.pro\/img\/John_Doe.jpg"
},
"5":{
"id":"8",
"name_first":"Caroline",
"name_last":"McCullough",
"industry":"IT",
"workplace":"Occupation",
"imageURL":"http:\/\/www.mothersdelight.com\/avatar\/avatar.jpg"
},
"6":{
"id":"11",
"name_first":"Akiko",
"name_last":"McDougall",
"industry":"IT",
"workplace":"Occupation",
"imageURL":"http:\/\/www.mothersdelight.com\/avatar\/avatar.jpg"
}
}
```

Note the added index for each item in the second example. This small change causes all sorts of problems client side, PHP is not my normal area and I am not sure why this block is changing the structure. Usually I would work around this on the client side, however, the product is already deployed.

Any insights or suggestions on how to prevent the iteration block from causing this integer index to appear would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you need to rearrange keys - use `array_values` after unsetting loop

Comment: Ordering is not the issue, the issue is each item in the array is getting numbered after it is processed through the iterator. This numbering screws with the consumer.

Comment: So if you have array with indexes `[0,1,2]` after unsetting index 1 you will have array with indexes `[0,2]`, after using `array_values` indexes will be `[0,1]` while values won't change.

Comment: The second example has a different entry added to it in place of the first one -- is that deliberate? It makes your examples unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @CBroe That's actually the problem the OP mentions.

Comment: By default _ordered_ arrays with numeric indices `(0,1,2..)` aren't showing any keys on output. However, when the order is abused, numerically indexed array becomes an _associative_, regardless the numeric indices it still holds, so PHP is showing the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/array_splice) to manipulate non-associative arrays safely:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($searchResponse);$i++){
    if($searchResponse[$i]['id']==$user_id){
        array_splice($searchResponse, $i, 1);
    }
}
```

`array_splice` takes the arguments

```
array_splice( $array, $offset, $length*, $replacementArr* )
```

with the second two arguments being optional. In this case, we want to remove one element from the array at index $i, so we use

```
array_splice( $searchResponse, $i, 1 );
```

Splicing can also be used to chop up arrays or replace array elements with another array, so it's a handy function to know.

Comment: How exactly `array_splice` in this case is better than using `array_values` on the sparsed array?

Comment: @raina77ow: TMTOWTDI.

Comment: Spot on mate, appreciate it!